# Get part of a string modifying the reference of a variable

Tags: ruby, string, reference

There is a way to return a part of a string and change the reference of a variable. For example:

```
old_string = 'hello this is a test'
```

A method that returns `'Hello'`, and `old_string` becomes `'this is a test'`.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
old_string = 'hello this is a test'
old_string.slice! /^\S+\s+/
```